# What is the absolute path of the Hadoop filesystem

Tags: java, hadoop

I can access `hadoop fs -ls /`
and I would like to know the absolute path of above `/`

I knew the `/` is a format looks like: "hdfs://host:port/"
I also knew it is the value of the setting `fs.defaultFS` in `core-site.xml`.

However, I checked my `core-site.xml`, and did not find `fs.defaultFS`'s value.
There must be a default value of `fs.defaultFS`, what is it?

Comment: It's `file://`. Not sure how you're able to access hdfs without setting that property. Check if you have `fs.default.name` instead.

Comment: what output you are getting for the command: `hdfs dfs -ls /`

Comment: I checked the document and understand fs.default.name is fs.defaultFS now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default value in the file `core-default.xml`, it is usually 
    `file:///`

Check `core-site.xml` for the value which is set by the user to override the default value which if present would something like

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://host:port</value>
</property>
```

the value can even be a service configured.

It is the default prefix of the Hadoop file system, by default it might look for `file://` which is your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can find default FS value from Command line:

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```